# When clicking on menu item not going to specific page

Tags: menus, pages

I have a menu with 4 list items and i have 4 php files with different page structure. And when i try to navigate to to other page i'm getting that requested url was not found. I don't know what exactly i'm doing wrong or what i'm missing. All this i'm doing on local Xampp server. 
This what i made so far.

**function.php**

```
function main_menu() {
    add_theme_support('menus');
    register_nav_menus(array(
        'primary' => __('Primary Main Menu'),
    ));
```

Menu located in home page

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

        <?php 

            $args = array(
            'container' => false,
            'menu_id' => false,
            'items-wrap' => '',
                'theme_location' => 'primary'
            );

            //Remove class and id from li elements

            add_filter('nav_menu_item_id', 'clear_nav_menu_item_id', 10, 3);
            function clear_nav_menu_item_id($id, $item, $args) {
                return "";
            }

            add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'clear_nav_menu_item_class', 10, 3);
            function clear_nav_menu_item_class($classes, $item, $args) {
                return array();
            }

            wp_nav_menu($args);

        ?>
    </ul>
```

Also in admin panel i checked "Primary Main Menu" checkboxe.

Comment: Did you try to flush your Permalink first? The URL not found issue normally happens due to permalink issue. Go to Setting -> Permalink and just click save/update button.

Comment: i tried this already, didn't help

Comment: are those 4 php files something like custom page templates, and attributed to 4 individual pages? are the menu links to those pages? what is the exact menu link that is not working?

Comment: yes they contains just other content, not working all of the menus except the main page. Basically the code that i posted its all what i've done, its my first wordpress project, maybe you can show an example how it must be attributed?

Comment: What do your menu items link to exactly? You can't link directly to php files, that's not how WordPress works- you link to WordPress pages/posts/categories/etc., and you create templates for those pages according to the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) to customize the look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed issue by renaming each file for menu tempalte-{file-name}.php and adding at beggining of file

```
/*
    Template Name: Page name
*/
```